# linking vbox lib with android lib

Tags: android, c, dynamic-linking, vbox

I am trying to use `vbox hgcm (ring-3)` from `android`. I have created a c file containing hgcm connect, disconnect, and call functions and compiled it (on ubuntu) for vbox.

I have to create another shared object for android which will use the vbox lib (created above) using dlopen/dlsym. My call to dlopen is getting failed with error:

```
cannot load library: link_image [2033]. failed to link <my_so_file_name>
```

I believe that android uses a different linker (bionic), and so directly linking the above two is giving me an error.

Any idea on how to fix it or any other approach for doing the same?

Comment: Bionic is really a C library, being/providing a dynamic linker is only secondary.  If you have the source for the non-android library, trying to port and compile it against bionic in the ndk build environment would be best.  Otherwise things are going to be messy - you may be able to do something by means of static linking the library so it has no external dependencies on non-android system libraries, but I would be on the lookout for assorted difficulties.